# Passport JWT authenticaten with cookie

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, passport.js

I have set a cookie with

```
res.cookie("auth", token);
```

how can I get it in a passport.js JWT Strategy to autehnticate my user
(I know there are lots of tutorials around the internet, but I didn't find any fitting for me)

This is what I have at the moment:

```
passport.use(new JwtStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest : req => req.cookies.auth,
    secretOrKey : config.secret
},
function(jwt_payload, done){
    if(jwt_payload.expires < Date.now()){
        User.findById(jwt_payload.id, (err, user) =>{
            if(err) return done(null, false);
            if(user){
                return done(null, true);
            }
        });
    }

    return done(null, false);
```

}));

[edit]
I have the code above in a separate file and I already performed a Test with Python and the cookie is stored in the browser

Comment: Your extractor function is correct if simple (doesn't handle errors). If it's not working can you post the rest of your app config code so we can see if you're configuring cookies correctly?

Comment: @Paul how would you solve this task? And in my case it alwys answers with a status code 401 Unauthorized if I'm trying to acess a protected route like: var auth = require('../auth/auth'); router.get('/test', auth.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), write_controller.test);

Comment: @timbiegeleisen thanks, I commented once, not sure why it posted twice. I deleted one.  STATIC like I said, I need to see your middleware setup to tell you what's wrong. Please post all your relevant code.